# Size of Array not showing the expectation

Tags: c

The goal is to get the number of even arrays and that of the odd arrays.
The output should be approximately 50% each, I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


int main()
{
    int arr[10]={0}, random_number, i, odd_saver[]={0}, even_saver[]={0};


    srand( time( NULL ) );
    for (i=0; i<10000; i++){
        random_number= (10*rand())/(RAND_MAX+1);
        arr[random_number]+=1;

        if (arr[random_number]%2==0){
            even_saver[random_number]+=1;
        }else{
           odd_saver[random_number]+=1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    size_t even_size = sizeof(even_saver[random_number]) / sizeof(even_saver[0]);
    size_t odd_size = sizeof(odd_saver[random_number]) / sizeof(odd_saver[0]);
    printf("%d %.2f%%\n", (int)even_size, (double)(even_size*100)/10000);
    printf("%d %.2f%%\n", (int)odd_size, (double)(odd_size*100)/10000);
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is not according to my expectation.
I need help, and more explanation about what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated.

The output:

```
1 0.01%
1 0.01%
```

Comment: C doesn't have dynamic arrays, their sizes are fixed. The arrays `odd_saver` and `even_saver` both have only *one single element*. And going out of bounds of an array (which you do) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On another note, should you really be calculating the odds and evens in the loop before all values are generated? That will give wrong results it seems. Use a second loop after the first for that.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and consider using [calloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html). If allowed, install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop, and study for inspiration the source code of many open source programs, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the reply, but please can you write the code that will fix my error and generate the expected output for clarity?

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to be invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi: notice that StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website. Your teacher is expecting *you* to debug your program. You could use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program.Your code has a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: You define `arr` with `10` elements, why can't you do it for the other two arrays? Then skip all elements who are zero.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is not what you call do-my-homework, the goal is more than that, this is just a sample code, I have written some code that I expect to work as expected, but since it's not working, it's nothing bad if you have a fix for me and if you don't I am ok with that.

Comment: Add a `printf("sizeof arr is %zd\n", sizeof(arr));` and similar calls for `sizeof(even_saver)`. Use also [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), it can show you that.

Answer (score 2):

As H.R. Emon has implied, in C you cannot create `odd_saver[]={0}, even_saver[]={0};` as arrays of size 1 and later try to increase their size by adding to them.

You aim to calculate your indexes for accessing all arrays in your code to be 0..9, which matches the array `arr` of size 10. (Though the method of calculating random numbers could be discussed...)

With that assumption, you can create all of your arrays the same way:

```
int arr[10]={0}, random_number, i, odd_saver[10]={0}, even_saver[10]={0};
```

I think your goal is to output the number of different even and different odd numbers (i.e. not counting multiple occurences of the same).
For that you cannot use the size of the even/odd arrays. For one because in C there are no dynamically growing arrays (as H.R. Emon has pointed out). But also because once you have an 8 or 9 occurring, incrementing that index in the arrays would (if such arrays would exist in C) falsely get you too high a size.

You will simply have to count the non-zeros in your even/odd arrays.

(By the way, it should be possible to use even/odd arrays of half the size, by dividing the index by 2 and using appropriate offsets.)

Answer (score 1):

i  am afraid you are trying to do things that c doesn't allow you to do. you are trying to invoke dynamic array in c. but c don't support dynamic array. so it will lead to you undefined behavior. if you need dynamic allocation you can use vector `std::vector` it's a `stl` function which helps you to use to allocate memory dynamically.

[vector details](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/)